# What is the Best Practice for placing validation messages using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using MVC4 but I imagine this is an issue for anyone using the new Bootstrap 3 version.  Since form-control is now width:100% by default, what is the best practice for placing validation messages?

In version 2.x, placing the validation messages in the help-inline span just after the input control worked best to ensure that the message was placed to the right of the control.
[image]

But in version 3, they always get pushed to the bottom making all the controls shift down because the validation messages are forced under the control.[image]

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="Label" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="Label" name="Label" type="text" value="">
        <span class="help-inline"><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Label" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Label" generated="true" class="">Required</span></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've considered manually setting them on a new column like this (below) but wondering if there was a more acceptable way or a less manual way of dealing with this.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="Label" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="Label" name="Label" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <p class="form-control-static"><span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Label" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Label" generated="true" class="">Required</span></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say there are "best practices" for presenting form validation errors. It's more of a personal design choice.

Depending on how much JS you want to write, you could get a little slick and insert an input group addon which holds an error message in a tooltip icon, like so...

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i data-toggle="tooltip" title="Error msg here" data-container="body" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Honestly though, I think messages appearing below input fields are fine, as long as they don't disturb page layout and push content down when they appear. (Which is just a matter of having a container that displays block and has a a hard-coded height.)

Comment: Clever trick!  I think I've settled on just adding a third "col-lg-*" div to contain the validation message but I may use your method in the future.